# How prevent discharging static electricity when touching metal case of sensitive circuit?

Tags: diodes, ground, zener, static-electricity

I have made a metal box including raspberry pi, touch screen and lcd screen. my problem is when i touch the box static electricity cause arc and shock to device and cause software failure also. i tried to connect all grounds to earth but:
1. it cause touch screen act weird
2. the earth connection is not available everywhere

i have an idea to connect metal box to ground using following circuit but i dont know if it would work or what part numbers should i use.
In my theory when the voltage rises more than 5v the zener diode should pass the current then resistor should convert electricity to heat. please correct me if i am wrong.
[image]

Comment: You seem to not understand zener diodes. What you described the diode doing is not what it does as drawn. You also do not seem to understand ESD as any diode is counter productive to begin with.

Comment: The diode isn't required. For one thing, because your metal box could be charged either positive or negative and you'd want to discharge it regardless.

Comment: ESD voltages can be 15,000V.  Remove the zener.  R is 1M.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEC_61000-4-2

Comment: What is the source of power for the Raspberry Pi?  Is it a desktop computer's USB port? Or a battery-powered laptop computer's USB port? Or a power adapter that converts AC wall power to 5 VDC power? Other?  The answer to this question plays an important role in your chassis grounding strategy.

Comment: Why is everything in a metal box in the first place? If the reason is: "A metal box is good for EMC" your question proves this is not always the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i have an idea to connect metal box to ground using following circuit but i dont know if it would work or what part numbers should i use. In my theory when the voltage rises more than 5v the zener diode should pass the current then resistor should convert electricity to heat.

Your circuit is fine, but the diode isn't required. Just use a resistor to ground. The resistor value can be as high as 10 megohm and it will allow charge to bleed off slowly without disturbing the circuit. Most likely you could even omit the resistor and just connect the box to ground with a wire --- this is probably how most of the appliances in your home are grounded, depending what jurisdiction you're in, and it works just fine.

The reason the diode is irrelevant is first because the static charge on the box could be either positive or negative, so you don't want to only discharge one kind of charge. Second because a zener will actually conduct in both directions, it will just take a higher voltage to conduct in one direction and a lower voltage to conduct in the other.

If you really want your box to be able to charge up to (say) 5 V in either direction, you should put two zeners in anti-series (in series but pointing opposite directions) in your circuit. But you haven't said anything about your application that would justify doing that.

Comment: Keep in mind that grounding the box won't prevent the ESD unless you're similarly grounded.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis can you explain me better? or give any link that demonstrate that?

Comment: https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/constructional_techniques/electrostatic-discharge/esd-protection.php

Answer (score 1):

The problem may not be that the metal box has a voltage potential with respect to ground  It may be that you have picked up a static charge (from the air, petting the cat, or rubbing your shoes on the carpet, etc.). If so, the best bet is to discharge yourself first, by slapping a nearby metal water faucet, etc. or other grounded appliance, before touching your sensitive electronics.  Or using a high impedance ground strap on your wrist, standing on a grounded static discharge mat, and etc.

Comment: this is not an option. imagine you discharge your self before touch your phone or laptop.

Comment: Discharging oneself is actually a required procedure in some electronics labs (standing on an ESD mat or attaching an ESD strap before touching anything on the lab bench.).